# No such file error when changing permissions of newly created HTML file in Python

Tags: python, selenium, permissions, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a process that downloads an html file using Selenium, Chromedriver and Ubuntu and then attempts to change the permissions of that file to 777. But it fails with "no such file or directory" error.

The thing is this, because I connect to a VPN using openvpn and disconnect several times during the process, I need to run it with root access.

I therefore have this shell script that I run using sudo bash ./nameofscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/imageTextAlgorithms/bin/activate
python ~/imageTextAlgorithms/DownloadURLs.py
```

After connecting to the VPN and downloading the desired file using Selenium, I run the following to save the file and change permissions:

```
filename = os.path.join(parentdir,"data","HTML",get_random_string(10))      
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite(filename)
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')

call('sudo chmod 777 ' + filename + ".html", shell=True)
call('sudo chmod -R 777 ' +  filename + "_files", shell=True)
```

Here parentdir is the full absolute path to the ~/imageTextAlgorithms directory where my code is located, and get_random_string(n) generates a random string of n lowercase characters, and I use pyautogui in order to make the browser download all images and css when saving, as opposed to just saving the html source file.

Those calls (the call function is from subprocess) give me a no such file error, but if I make the exact same call from an OS Command line it is successful. Also, I already tried using the python function os.chmod with no success.

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe first check `os.listdir()` to see if this file exists. Maybe you are in wrong folder, or it uses different name when it downloads and later it renames. Or Maybe you need some `time.sleep()` so it will have time to finish work.

Comment: It was a timing issue, as suggested in my answer below. Thanks very much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by furas in comments, it was a timing issue.
It turns out that there is a wait time between pyautogui pressing enter to the save dialog box and the files being in the system, as chrome downloads everything again when you save the page.
So I changed the calls to sudo chmod for this and now it works as expected:

```
    while True:
                try:
                    os.chmod( filename + ".html",0o777)
                    os.chmod( filename + "_files",0o777)
                    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk( filename + "_files"):
                        for dirname in dirnames:
                            path = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
                            os.chmod(path, 0o777)
                        for filename in filenames:
                            path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                            os.chmod(path, 0o777)
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    sleep(1)
```